# Creating new rows in a file geodatabase table in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, table, domains

I have a File Geodatabase Table with 2 domains which I would like to display in an ArcGIS Online dashboard. I have zipped and uploaded this FGDB into AG-Online and edit exisiting rows. I cannot however write new rows. Is this not supported?

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that you have performed when trying to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I have never zipped and uploaded a full GDB into ArcGIS Online (AGOL). Usually my workflow is to host a feature class, from a GDB, as a feature service to AGOL which will honor any domains you've created. Then you'll have full editing capabilities assuming your organization allows you editing privileges. You'd also have to enable editing in AGOL under the service's "Settings" page.